# How to use inherited properties in EF Core expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We need construct expression for EF in dynamic way. For example create test models:

```
public class TestBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestCard : TestBase
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}
```

Create a linq query:

```
var q = from card in Context.hlt_disp_Card
        select new TestCard
        {
            Id = card.disp_CardID,
            Guid = card.Guid
        };
```

Normal using expressions:

```
Expression<Func<TestCard, bool>> ex1 = card => card.Id == 1030;

q.Where(ex1).ToList();
```

We require create expression from any type and always we have a string name of property, thus we tried construct it in this way:

```
var e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TestCard), "card");
Expression bin = Expression.Property(e, "Id");
bin = Expression.Equal(bin, Expression.Constant(1030));
var ex2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TestCard, bool>>(bin, e);

q.Where(ex2).ToList();
```

But we got a warning:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[8]
>   The LINQ expression '(new TestCard() {Id = [card].disp_CardID, Guid =
>   [card].Guid}.Id == 1030)' could not be translated and will be
>   evaluated locally. To configure this warning use the
>   DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API (event id
>   'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning'). ConfigureWarnings
>   can be used when overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or
>   using AddDbContext on the application service provider.

We checked resulting SQL in profiler and got this results:
q.Where(ex1).ToList(); built to

```
SELECT [card].[disp_CardID], [card].[Guid]
FROM [hlt_disp_Card] AS [card]
WHERE [card].[disp_CardID] = 1030
```

and q.Where(ex2).ToList(); built to

```
SELECT [card].[disp_CardID], [card].[Guid]
FROM [hlt_disp_Card] AS [card]
```

And if I try construct filter for **not-inherited** property (eg Guid) my way works well!

EF Core version: 1.0.1

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, this sounds like another EF Core bug (happens also in v.1.1.0 (release)).

The only difference between the two expressions is the [`ReflectedType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype(v=vs.110).aspx) of the property accessor expression [`Member`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.member(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can fix it this way:

```
// ...
var p = e.Type.GetProperty("Id");
if (p.ReflectedType != p.DeclaringType)
    p = p.DeclaringType.GetProperty(p.Name);
Expression bin = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(e, p);
// ...
```

but it's weird to have such requirement, I would suggest reporting the issue to [EF Core GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues).

Comment: Thank you, I will try this way. And I have already created issure... https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7126
Maybe you have any accounts in social networks? I want discuss this issue in native language...

Comment: I'm not using social networks. But I can open a chat room here if you wish.

Comment: Okay, how to do it?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129108/discussion-between-ivan-stoev-and-vladislav