# EF Core 3.1 Generated Expressions at Runtime all fail with unable to processes query on server

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

In the past we could use code like this:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
{
    // LAMBDA: x => x.[PropertyName]
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
    Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

    // REFLECTION: source.OrderBy(x => x.Property)
    var orderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    var orderByGeneric = orderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), property.Type);
    var result = orderByGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });

    return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)result;
}
```

To do an order by, but this now fails in EF Core 3.1

And use in source.QueryBy(x => EF.Property(x, "Name")) gives an inproper use of EF.Property error so I'm at a loss as to how I can avoid these errors and still build up dynamic expression tries on an IQueryable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would be helpful if you also post the actual exception message that happens during query execution

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong - EF Core is doing it wrong "for you" :-(

Not sure what you mean by "in the past", but EF Core has problems with some what they call "non compiler generated" expressions from the very beginning like the following SO posts

[How to use inherited properties in EF Core expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805830/how-to-use-inherited-properties-in-ef-core-expressions/40807375#40807375m)

[Why Linq "where" expression after Select gets evaluated locally when created through a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389115/why-linq-where-expression-after-select-gets-evaluated-locally-when-created-thr/57392731#57392731)

[The LINQ expression could not be translated for base property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295009/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated-for-base-property/55296106#55296106)

and many GitHub issues like

[Building Filter and/or OrderBy via Expression on Intermediate type throws InvalidOpException #19087](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19087)

Looks like finally it has been fixed with [Query: Match memberInfo in hierarchy for reducing MemberInitExpression #19182](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/19182), but unfortunately not included in 3.1, so we have to wait for 5.0 at the end of the year (for 1 line change!).

Until then, you have to use the mentioned workarounds, for instance use the following `Expression.Property` replacement (basically the code from [How to use inherited properties in EF Core expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805830/how-to-use-inherited-properties-in-ef-core-expressions/40807375#40807375m)):

```
static MemberExpression Property(Expression expression, string propertyName)
{
    var propertyInfo = expression.Type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (propertyInfo.ReflectedType != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        propertyInfo = propertyInfo.DeclaringType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expression, propertyInfo);  
}
```

e.g.

```
var property = Property(propertyName);
```

should fix the issue.

---

Unrelated, but you can also improve your method in two ways.

First, you can easily add support for nested properties through dot separated string like "Prop1.Prop2.Prop3" by using

```
var property = propertyName.Split(".")
    .Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Property);
```

Second, instead of reflection you can simply emit `Expression.Call` to `Queryable.OrderBy`.

The whole method could be like this:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");
    var property = propertyName.Split(".")
        .Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Property);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(property, new[] { parameter });
    var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.OrderBy),
        new[] { source.ElementType, property.Type },
        new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector) });
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)source.Provider.CreateQuery(expression);
}
```